# Length of array in an excel column

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a column in excel which has arrays. Meaning , they have a list of comma separated values enclosed within curly braces like below

```
{a}
{a,b}
{a,b,c}
{d,e,f} 
..
```

Is there any way i can determine length of each array using a simple excel calculation , or do I require some code. The deisred output would be ..

```
{a}                  --   1
{a,b}                --   2
{a,b,c}              --   3
{d,e,f}              --   3
..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find array length in `A1` you can count commas and add 1:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```